# Update de componentes em tempo real no Angular

Tags: angular, api

Olá, pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou iniciando meus estudos com angular e estou com um problema de implementação. Tenho uma API, desenvolvida por mim, na qual os dados retornados são atualizados a cada 20 segundos no servidor.

Estou montando um frontend com angular. A ideia é atualizar a view do usuário a cada 20 segundos também (ou menos até). Mas existe um requisito funcional da aplicação, que resume-se a notificar (visualmente) o usuário, quando valor de atributo for alterado.

Para um componente renderizado da seguinte forma:

```
<div *ngFor="event in events">
    <app-event
        [id]="event.id"
        [time]="event.time"
        [value1]="event.value1" >
    </app-events>
</div>
```

Sendo uma chamada de exemplo **(chamada n)**

```
"events" : [
    {
        "id" : 1
        "time" : 45,
        "value1" : 1.6
    },
    {
        "id" : 2
        "time" : 78,
        "value1" : 1.5
    }
]
```

Na **chamada n+1**:

```
"events" : [
    {
        "id" : 1
        "time" : 46,
        "value1" : 1.5
    },
    {
        "id" : 2
        "time" : 78,
        "value1" : 1.6
    }
]
```

Os valores de `time` e `value1` foram alterados na api na **chamada n+1**, portando, preciso alterar a classe do component que ele fora renderizado na **chamada n**. Eu li sobre questões que envolvem Subject, Observable e outras coisas, mas não ficou tão claro para mim, como executar isso.

Abaixo o código atual dos meus componentes.

`events.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { EventsService } from '../../services/events.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.scss']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

  events = []
  
  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe((data: any[]) => {         
      this.events = data
    })


  }


}
```

`events.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    
  }

  private API_URL = "http://0.0.0.0:93"

  public getEvents(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL}/events/inplay`)    
  }
}
```

`events.component.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events.data">
    <app-event [event]="event"></app-event>
</div>
```

`event.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges,  } from '@angular/core';
import { SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core'
import { EventsComponent } from '../events.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-event',
  templateUrl: './event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event.component.scss']
})
export class EventComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() event: any;

  constructor(private eventsComponent: EventsComponent) {

   }


  ngOnInit(): void {       

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {       
    console.log(changes)    
  }
 
}
```

Agradeço.

Comment: Tanto **Subject** como **Behaviour Subject**  são indicados para atualizações de dados entre componentes que necessitam atualizar valores de um componente através de outro componente  e não dados de uma API. Acho que isso é bem simples de resolver inserindo um método `JavaScript` **setInterval()** na chamada do service no arquivo **`events.component.ts`**, isso atualizaria os dados no tempo que for determinado no método, ou, utilizar métodos específicos do `Angular/RXJS` para isso, como o **`timer`**: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer

Comment: Tudo bem, eu até fiz isso e acabei esquecendo de colocar nos códigos de exemplo. O problema é: Como vou identificar que os dados foram alterados e notificar o usuário (visualmente, uma mudança de classe, por exemplo) dessa alteração?

Comment: Não sei se existem métodos prontos para isso, ou, teria que criar na mão. Mas se não tiver pronto vc consegue comparando os valores dos objetos em **this.events**. Pega o valor atual e verifica se o valor que a atualização trouxe ainda é igual ao atual.

Comment: Pois é, atualmente essa aplicação está construída em Jquery e faço exatamente assim. Acredito que será a única alternativa.

Comment: Você pode utilizar sockets ao inves de http, ai seu back notifica o front que algo mudou

Answer (score -1):

Se o seu backend ainda não oferece WebSockets ou SSE, vc pode fazer por meio de polling:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    interval(20000).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.eventsService.getEvents()),
        distinctUntilChanged((prev, nxt) => prev.time === nxt.time && prev.value1 === nxt.value1),
    ).subscribe(
        evt => console.log(`time or value1 changed`, evt),
    )
}
```

---

Se o seu backend oferecer SSE, você poderia deixar a lógica de comparação nele e no frontend só receber os eventos:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    const eventSource = new EventSource('url/do/sse');
    eventSource.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
        console.log(`received server event`, event);
    };
}
```